# Clicking option in a custom dropdown [React component with outside click function & array of refs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown, use-ref

I have a component with a custom dropdown and the function for closing the dropdown on clicking anywhere outside the component works as it should (see below):

```
const [isDropdownOpen, setIsDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
const dropdownRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
      const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
        if (dropdownRef.current && !dropdownRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
          setIsDropdownOpen(false)
        }
      }
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      
      return () => { //cleanup function
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      };
    });

const toggleDropDown = () => {
   setIsDropdownOpen(!isDropdownOpen)
}

return (
 <div onClick={toggleDropDown}> click here
  {isDropdownOpen && (
    <div ref={dropdownRef}>
        <div onClick={handleOption2}>Option 1</div>
        <div onClick={handleOption2}>Option 2</div>
    </div>
  )}
</div> 
)
```

When I dynamically create the component for each item in an array, I use an **array of refs** instead and I write the outside click function as shown below:

```
const [allDropdownOpen, setAllDropdownOpen] = useState([]);
const dropdownRefs = useRef([]);

// set false dropdown states for all items in array (the array is fetched through an API call)
useEffect(() => {
 if(fetchedArray) {
  let arr = [];
  fetchedArray.forEach(() => arr.push(false));
  setAllDropdownOpen(arr)
 }
}, [fetchedArray])

useEffect(() => {
    let arr = [];
    if(fetchedArray) {
      fetchedArray.forEach(() => arr.push(false)); //create false states for all items in array
    }

    const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
       if(dropdownRefs.current.some(ref => ref && !ref.contains(e.target))) {
          setAllDropdownOpen(arr) //close all dropdowns
       }
    }
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      
    return () => { //cleanup function
       document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
});

const toggleDropDown = (index) => {
 //change dropdown state for selected item
 const arr = [...allDropdownOpen];
 arr[index] = !arr[index];
 setAllDropdownOpen([...arr]);
}

return (
 <div>
  {fetchedArray.map((data, i) => (
    <div 
      onClick={() => toggleDropDown(i)} 
      ref={el => (dropdownRefs.current[i] = el)}
    > 
      click here
    
     {allDropdownOpen[i] && (
       <div>
        <div onClick={handleOption2}>Option 1</div>
        <div onClick={handleOption2}>Option 2</div>
       </div>
     )}
   </div> 
  )}
</div>
)
```

Although this works and the dropdowns close, the issue I'm facing now is that when I click an option in the dropdown list "Option 1" or "Option 2", it doesn't execute `handleOption1` or `handleOption2` . It just closes all dropdowns.

I've confirmed that the options are in fact clickable and they execute when I remove the `useEffect` hook with the `handleOutsideClick` function so I know the error is from there.

How do I avoid this and correctly target the dropdown of the clicked array item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****UPDATE**** : **I FINALLY FOUND MY ACTUAL ERROR!**

I was attaching the `ref` to the wrong element! It was attached to the parent `div` with the `onClick` property when it should have been attached to the dropdown itself (as it was in the code for a single component)‍♀️:

So this part:

```
return (
 <div>
  {fetchedArray.map((data, i) => (
    <div 
      onClick={() => toggleDropDown(i)} 
      ref={el => (dropdownRefs.current[i] = el)}
    > 
      click here

     {allDropdownOpen[i] && (
       <div>
        <div onClick={handleOption2}>Option 1</div>
        <div onClick={handleOption2}>Option 2</div>
       </div>
     )}
   </div> 
  )}
</div>
)}
```

should have been:

```
return (
 <div>
  {fetchedArray.map((data, i) => (
    <div 
      onClick={() => toggleDropDown(i)} 
    > 
      click here

     {allDropdownOpen[i] && (
       <div ref={el => (dropdownRefs.current[i] = el)}>
        <div onClick={handleOption2}>Option 1</div>
        <div onClick={handleOption2}>Option 2</div>
       </div>
     )}
   </div> 
  )}
</div>
)}
```

Such a tiny mistake and it cost me all of my braincells‍♀️‍♀️

.
.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

After an endless night of searching for my error, I decided to go this route:

1. initialise a `currentDropdownIndex` state,
2. set its value as the index of the item whenever its dropdown is clicked,
3. use the index to target the ref individually for the item

```
    const Wrapper = () => {
    
    const [allDropdownOpen, setAllDropdownOpen] = useState([]);    
    const [currentDropdownIndex, setCurrentDropdownIndex] = useState(null);
    const dropdownRefs = useRef([]);
    
    // set false dropdown states for all items in array (the array is fetched through an API call)
    useEffect(() => {
     if(fetchedArray) {
      let arr = [];
      fetchedArray.forEach(() => arr.push(false));
      setAllDropdownOpen(arr)
     }
    }, [fetchedArray])
    
    //target ref of clicked dropdown using currentDropdownIndex
    useEffect(() => {
        let arr = [];
        if(fetchedArray) {
          fetchedArray.forEach(() => arr.push(false));
        }
       const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
       if(dropdownRefs.current[currentDropdownIndex] && 
         !dropdownRefs.current[currentDropdownIndex].contains(e.target))) {
          setAllDropdownOpen(arr)
       }
      }
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      };
});

 //change dropdown state for selected item
const toggleDropDown = (index) => {
 const arr = [...allDropdownOpen];
 arr[index] = !arr[index];
 setAllDropdownOpen([...arr]);
 setCurrentDropdownIndex(index); //set dropdown index to clicked array item
}

return (
 <div>
  {fetchedArray.map((data, i) => (
    <div 
      onClick={() => toggleDropDown(i)} 
      ref={el => (dropdownRefs.current[i] = el)}
    > 
      click here

 {allDropdownOpen[i] && (
   <div ref={dropdownRef}>
    <div onClick={handleOption2}>Option 1</div>
    <div onClick={handleOption2}>Option 2</div>
   </div>
 )}

   </div> 
  )}
</div>
)}
```

And yeah, it worked.